# Django m2m produce Unnecessary inner join, that change SQL result

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm

Django 2.1.4 (the like behavior exist on 2.0.4 too)
Models:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    # many fileds
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    seers = models.ManyToManyField('Agency', through='ApplicationAgencySeer')
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)  

class ApplicationAgencySeer(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agency = models.ForeignKey('Agency', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now I wanna filter

```
# count 0
Application.objects.filter(seers__agency__id='c3e5ed58-a4d9-4ca6-a8f7-6793eb8e3e24').count()  # 0
# but count 1
ApplicationAgencySeer.objects.filter(agency__id='c3e5ed58-a4d9-4ca6-a8f7-6793eb8e3e24').count()  # 1
```

```
   SELECT *
   FROM "app_application"
          INNER JOIN "myapp_applicationagencyseer"
                     ON ("app_application"."id" = "app_applicationagencyseer"."application_id")
          INNER JOIN "myapp_agency"
                     ON ("app_applicationagencyseer"."agency_id" = "app_agency"."organization_ptr_id")
          INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" T4 ON ("app_agency"."organization_ptr_id" = T4."parent_id")
   WHERE T4."organization_ptr_id" = 'c3e5ed58-a4d9-4ca6-a8f7-6793eb8e3e24'
```

if remove `INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" T4 ON ("app_agency"."organization_ptr_id" = T4."parent_id")` all be right.

WHY parent_id why-why

I found the bug, maybe it some related <[djangoproject](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20535)> but 6 years ago. I think it already fixes before 2.1.4 release. 
How to me compose right filter query, or avoid this situation. help me I am stuck.

```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM "myapp_application"
   WHERE NOT ("myapp_application"."id" IN (SELECT U1."application_id"
                                              FROM "myapp_applicationagencyseer" U1
                                                     INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" U2 ON (U1."agency_id" = U2."organization_ptr_id")
                                                     INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" U3 ON (U2."organization_ptr_id" = U3."parent_id")
                                              WHERE U3."organization_ptr_id" = '9e71cff4-443d-4c60-ac2d-9dcca2a9c147'))
   ORDER BY "myapp_application"."created_date" DESC;

   result

   application_id
   7d83d056-5a7d-4095-9037-98bde29a3d78    otherfields..
   7cb60afc-109d-4570-ad24-6cad6b7ddd9a    otherfields..   <-- this row error


   --return 0
   (SELECT U1."application_id"
    FROM "myapp_applicationagencyseer" U1
                INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" U2 ON (U1."agency_id" = U2."organization_ptr_id")
                INNER JOIN "myapp_agency" U3 ON (U2."organization_ptr_id" = U3."parent_id")
    WHERE U3."organization_ptr_id" = '9e71cff4-443d-4c60-ac2d-9dcca2a9c147')

   --althouth I have  myapp_applicationagencyseer
   id       created                   agency_id                                   application_id               status
   1    2018-12-10 17:41:14.272684  9e71cff4-443d-4c60-ac2d-9dcca2a9c147    7cb60afc-109d-4570-ad24-6cad6b7ddd9a    1
   2    2018-12-11 19:25:58.818000  9e71cff4-443d-4c60-ac2d-9dcca2a9c147    7cb60afc-109d-4570-ad24-6cad6b7ddd9a    0

   -- myapp_agency
   organization_ptr_id                 accreditation   parent
   aff44d42-ce81-4c3e-b6e1-056ed9351adb Null           Null
   9e71cff4-443d-4c60-ac2d-9dcca2a9c147 10АА71         Null       <-- It have Null parent
```

Comment: Did you create your `ApplicationAgencySeer` record like so: `ApplicationAgencySeer.objects.create(agency=Agency.objects.get(id='c3e5ed58-a4d9-4ca6-a8f7-6793eb8e3e24', application=Applications.objects.create(…))`?

Comment: `agencies_application = zip_longest(applications, [], fillvalue=agency)` \n 
        `seers = map(lambda x: ApplicationAgencySeer(agency=x[1], application=x[0]), agencies_application)`  \n
        `ApplicationAgencySeer.objects.bulk_create(seers)`

Comment: @madjardi - did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: I think this was Django bug, I wrote to the official Django-google-group, but no one gives me an answer. I changed the SQL query(queryset). Sadly